# No WP-Content Folder in Website Files, No Ability to Disable Plugins Manually

Tags: plugins, errors, ssh

While updating some plugins on my Wordpress site recently, I encountered a critical error, which I suspect to be the result of an update failure. I can't access WP-Admin and so used Filezilla to try and identify the plugins folder and temporarily disable all plugins. The problem is, when I try and use SSH to get access to the site, I cannot identify any folders labeled WP-Content or Plugins. I'm a fairly novice web developer, so is there something I am missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: that looks like the top level root of a Linux/*nix environment, the equivalent of `C:/` on a PC. `httpdocs` looks close to a common public webroot, but it will depend on how that server was initially set up

Comment: To add to @TomJNowell's comment: `var/www/` is often a location to look for website files. They might be in a subdirectory—for instance, most of my sites are located in `/var/www/vhosts/` on their respective Linux servers.